# why are my buttons duplicating when i reopen them (python tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
    import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import turtle
from turtle import *



wn = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
root = Tk()
root.title("control board")
turtle.title("drawing board")
root["bg"] = "black"
wn.bgcolor("black")
t.color("white")

root2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
root2.withdraw()
root3 = tk.Toplevel(root)
root3.withdraw()
root4 = tk.Toplevel(root)
root4.withdraw()


def circle():
    t.circle(50)
def line():
    b7.pack()
    b8.pack()
    b9.pack()
    b2.forget()
def l_line():
    t.left(30)
def r_line():
    t.right(30)

def check():
    b5.config(text = "u sure?", command = doublecheck)
def doublecheck():
    turtle.bye()
    root.destroy()
def sf():
    t.forward(10)
def bf():
    t.forward(50)
def hidef():
    b7.forget()
    b8.forget()
    b9.forget()
    b19.forget()
    b2.pack()
    b19.pack()
def colors():
    root3.deiconify
    root3.title("theme window")
    b11 = Button(root3, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="BLUE", fg="white",
                 text="blue",
                 command=bluec, )

    b12 = Button(root3, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="red", fg="white",
                 text="red",
                 command=redc, )

    b13 = Button(root3, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="yellow", fg="white",
                 text="yellow",
                 command=yellowc, )

    b22 = Button(root3, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="black", fg="yellow",
                 text="close color window",
                 command=root3.destroy, )

    b11.pack()
    b12.pack()
    b13.pack()
    b22.pack()
def bluec():
    t.color("blue")
def redc():
    t.color("red")
def yellowc():
    t.color("yellow")
def undo():
    t.undo()
def themes():
    root2.deiconify()
    root2.title("theme window")
    b16 = Button(root2, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="yellow", fg="blue",
                 text="hannukah theme",
                 command=htheme, )
    b17 = Button(root2, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="white", fg="red",
                 text="christmas theme",
                 command=ctheme, )
    b22 = Button(root2, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="white", fg="red",
                 text="customize themes",
                 command=customthemehub)

    b18 = Button(root2, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="black", fg="yellow",
                 text="close theme window",
                 command= root2.destroy, )
    b16.pack()
    b17.pack()
    b22.pack()
    b18.pack()
def htheme():
    wn.bgcolor("yellow")
    t.color("blue")
    root["bg"] = "yellow"
    b1["bg"] = "blue"
    b2["bg"] = "blue"
    b3["bg"] = "blue"
    b4["bg"] = "blue"
    b5["bg"] = "blue"
    b7["bg"] = "blue"
    b8["bg"] = "blue"
    b9["bg"] = "blue"
    b14["bg"] = "blue"
    b15["bg"] = "blue"


    b1["fg"] = "yellow"
    b2["fg"] = "yellow"
    b3["fg"] = "yellow"
    b4["fg"] = "yellow"
    b5["fg"] = "yellow"
    b7["fg"] = "yellow"
    b8["fg"] = "yellow"
    b9["fg"] = "yellow"
    b14["fg"] = "yellow"
    b15["fg"] = "yellow"

def ctheme():
    wn.bgcolor("red")
    t.color("white")
    root["bg"] = "red"
    b1["bg"] = "white"
    b2["bg"] = "white"
    b3["bg"] = "white"
    b4["bg"] = "white"
    b5["bg"] = "white"
    b7["bg"] = "white"
    b8["bg"] = "white"
    b9["bg"] = "white"

    b14["bg"] = "white"
    b15["bg"] = "white"

    b1["fg"] = "red"
    b2["fg"] = "red"
    b3["fg"] = "red"
    b4["fg"] = "red"
    b5["fg"] = "red"
    b7["fg"] = "red"
    b8["fg"] = "red"
    b9["fg"] = "red"
    b14["fg"] = "red"
    b15["fg"] = "red"

def penswitch():
    b20.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
    b21.pack(side = tkinter.BOTTOM)
    b19.forget()
def penu():
    t.penup()
    b20.forget()
    b21.forget()
    b19.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
def pend():
    t.pendown()
    b20.forget()
    b21.forget()
    b19.pack()

def customthemehub():
    root4.deiconify()
    b23 = Button(root4, height=2,
                 width=20,
                 bg="black", fg="blue",
                 text="select background color",
                 command=bgselect, )


    b10 = Button(root4, height=2,
         width=20,
        bg="black", fg="white",
        text="select drawing color",
        command=colors )
    b10.pack()
    b23.pack()

def bluebg():
    wn.bgcolor("blue")
def yellowbg():
    wn.bgcolor("yellow")

root5 = tk.Toplevel(root)

b24 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="blue", fg="white",
             text="blue background",
             command=bluebg)

b25 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="yellow", fg="white",
             text="yellow background",
             command=yellowbg)

b24.pack()
b25.pack()
root5.withdraw()

def bgselect():
    root4.withdraw()
    root5.deiconify()



b1 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text="circle",
             command=circle,)

b2 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg = "black", fg = "white",
             text="line",
             command=line,)

b3 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text=" turn left",
             command= l_line ,)

b4 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text=" turn right",
             command= r_line ,)

b5 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text=" exit",
             command= check ,)



b7 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text="10 steps",
             command= sf,)

b8 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text="50 steps",
             command= bf,)

b9 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
            bg="black", fg="white",
             text="hide",
             command= hidef,)




b14 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text="undo last action",
             command= undo,)

b15 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text="select different themes",
             command= themes,)

b19 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text="pen up/down",
             command= penswitch,)

b20 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text="pen up",
             command= penu,)
b21 = Button(root, height = 2,
             width = 20,
bg="black", fg="white",
             text="pen down",
             command= pend,)


b15.pack()
b14.pack()

b5.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT, )
b4.pack()
b3.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
b19.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

sorry for the annoying code i know its a complete mess, basically the problem is with def: bgselecr and the choosing color, if anyone can run this code the click on the custom themes then customize theme then choose background color, when i close it and reopen the tab of the background color it "duplicates" the buttons i use the withdraw and deiconify method, if u need i can re-explain what i mean i have no idea what causes it, any help would be aprecitaed

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PELEG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\PELEG\PycharmProjects\idk\main.py", line 232, in bgselect
    root5.deiconify()
  File "C:\Users\PELEG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2013, in wm_deiconify
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'deiconify', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel5"
```

these are the errors after the code

Comment: Please post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you! While doing this, there is a good chance you will find where the problem is.

Comment: Yes a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will be helpful to solve the problem at its earliest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem with your code here is that for any window(`Toplevel`) that you have initialized, you initially `withdraw` it but whenever you `deiconify` it again, you pack two new buttons to it.

So for example lets take the background color selection window, the first time you run the function `bgselect()`, it packs two buttons of the two colors to select from into the window. Now when you close the window, in reality the window along with the two buttons still exists and just has been withdrawn.

This means that the next time you `deiconify` it, the old two packed buttons will still be there and there is no need to pack two new buttons to it again.

[image: Here the red part shows the code which messes stuff up. This code initializes two new buttons everytime and packs it into the window that already has the old packed buttons.]

Now, the solution to this problem is to add these buttons when you initialize the `Toplevel` widgets.
When going through your code it seems like all the `Toplevel` widgets have been configured in the manner which leads to repeated packing of new buttons.
By removing the packing code from the functions and relocating it to the lines where all the `Toplevel`s are initialized, the problem gets solved!

[image: The red lines in this image of your code indicate where to add the packing code.]

For example for `root5` it will look like this after the fix -:

```
def bluebg():
    wn.bgcolor("blue")
def yellowbg():
    wn.bgcolor("yellow")

root5 = tk.Toplevel(root)
# Buttons are initialized once.
b24 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="blue", fg="white",
             text="blue background",
             command=bluebg)

b25 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="yellow", fg="white",
             text="yellow background",
             command=yellowbg)

b24.pack()
b25.pack()
root5.withdraw()

def bgselect():
    root4.withdraw()
    root5.deiconify()
    # Buttons are no longer repeatedly initialized.
```

**EDIT:**
As informed by you in comments, after making the changes suggested above, you run into the following error-:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\PELEG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\PELEG\PycharmProjects\idk\main.py", line 232, in bgselect
> root5.deiconify()   File "C:\Users\PELEG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 2013, in wm_deiconify
> return self.tk.call('wm', 'deiconify', self._w)
> _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel5"

The error above occurs as the root5 and other `Toplevel` windows are destroyed when they close rather than being withdrawn, and when you open them you deiconify them, but they already have been destroyed, so it throws an error.

The same can be fixed by calling the withdraw function on all `Toplevel`s by binding it to their `'WM_DELETE_WINDOW'` protocol, which will trigger when window close button is pressed.

Like so-:

```
root5 = tk.Toplevel(root)
# Buttons are initialized once.
b24 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="blue", fg="white",
             text="blue background",
             command=bluebg)

b25 = Button(root5, height=2,
             width=20,
             bg="yellow", fg="white",
             text="yellow background",
             command=yellowbg)

b24.pack()
b25.pack()
root5.withdraw()
root5.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root5.withdraw) # Binds the protocol to the callback
```

Now the same line has to be added in the initialization of all `Toplevel`s.
This fixes the error.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try it later since my laptop isn't on me right now

Comment: No problem, Make sure you improve the readability of the question so its easier for future viewers to understand it! Thanks for using SO!

Comment: yeah mostly i go into to detail its just i was in school writing that, also i honestly didnt really know myself what i was doing so couldnt really explain in

Comment: so sorry for the hassle but i ran the code that you sent and it doesnt work when i close it and rerun it 
i edited the original with the error code

Comment: @pelegsiegel Can you also edit the question and add the full code you are currently using? That may be useful to find the reason for the error. Thanks!

Comment: i just edited it, it isnt exactly what i used since i got frustrated and tried restarting but its as close as i got, again so sorry for the hassle its just i have no idea what i am doing when it comes to this

Comment: I might just have found the reason for it, which is that the window does not get withdrawn when closed, so I am on my way to write a solution!

Comment: wow thank you so much, i was looking everywhere but it seems no one else has had this problem

Comment: Solved! I am adding it into the question

Comment: thank you so much, did you edit it in the original comment you made? i cant seem to find it

Comment: I have edited my original answer, please check and try if the new solution works. I have tried it personally and it seems to be working for me!